# question on MVC data annotations, editor templates, and validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4, data-annotations

Context: MVC 2 app using EF.

Why does some of this work, but some doesn't?  The display name gets set to "Court Name" but no validation is happening, i.e. I don't see the error message.  I'm thinking the editor templates are interfering with validation, or else Model.IsValid doesn't work with a complex view model.

Any thoughts?

PARTIAL CLASS:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(CourtMetaData))]
public partial class Court
{

    private class CourtMetaData
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Court Name is required")]
        [DisplayName("Court Name")]
        public System.String CourtName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

    }

}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult New(CourtsNewViewModel court)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.AddCourt(court);
        return View("List");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("New", court);
    }
}
```

VIEW MODEL:

```
public class CourtsNewViewModel : ViewModelBase
{

    public Court Court {get; private set; }

    public IEnumerable<CourtType> CourtTypes { get; private set; }

    public CourtsNewViewModel()
    {
        CourtTypes = db.GetAllCourtTypes();
    }

}
```

VIEW:

```
Html.EditorFor(model => model.Court.CourtName, "LongString")
```

EDITOR TEMPLATE:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<System.String>" %>
<div class="editor-row">
<div class="editor-label">
    <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model) %>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model)%>
    <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model) %>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the gotcha:

```
public ActionResult New(CourtsNewViewModel court)
```

The `court` variable is already used as you have a `Court` property on your model.

Now rename the parameter:

```
public ActionResult New(CourtsNewViewModel courtModel)
```

Everything should work as expected.